# What are the custom roms available in market for android and ios for micromax funbook P 300?

Tags: applications

I am working to add custom rom that are available for ios and android,I need to add add custom rom in my android phones, I was using **"androios"** rom that is featured for both  ios and android, but its not rebooting properly in

> **`micromax funbook p300`**

Can any one please help me, Regarding Custom Roms that have features of both ios and android, to add in micromax funbook p300.

Comment: Have you checked [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can't install iOS on your Funbook. Any ROM(s) that claim in doing so are actually just running Android with a launcher that looks like iOS.

For information about ROMs for the P300 I suggest you read [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2313795). The number of working ROMs as is seems pretty scarce.

Also, when you root, unlock your bootloader or flash a custom ROM you void any warranty of your device.